# Python - Selenium Unable to locate element on Search button

Tags: python, selenium, button, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to locate and click on a button "Search" on *internal website* using python selenium. 
The element with class = *"button"*:

```
<a href="javascript:showSearch(true)" title="Search" class="button" id="button_search">
    <img src="images/icon_search.gif" alt="">Search
  </a>
```

When click, this button will show a table containing many search filters, and the class changes to *"button_active"*

```
<a href="javascript:showSearch(true)" title="Search" class="button_active" id="button_search">
    <img src="images/icon_search.gif" alt="">Search
  </a>
```

And xpath is:

```
//*[@id="button_search"]
```

[locate the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ujjc.png)

Packages:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I've tried all the following code:

```
search_button = driver.find_element_by_id('button_search')
or 
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="button_search"]')))
or
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="Search" and @class="button" and @id="button_search"]')))
```

and many way by ID, LINK_TEXT.... but I always get the same error that:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button_search"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
```

Do you have any ideas why it may not be able to locate this button? 
Thank you!

Edit:
I've tried `switch_to.frame` and it works!
Thank you all!

Comment: try using any chrome extension for detecting element, like css checker and verify if you id is really actually pointing to that. This happens generally if you have incorrect selector for the element.

Comment: Hi, i've carefully inspect the button and verified the ID, I also  added a picture capturing the element and its css in the question.

Comment: please share little more HTML code or site URL

Comment: Please add link to site that you are testing.

Comment: always add url to page so we can see real and full HTML. Maybe this element is inside `<frame>` and then you have to use `switch_to.frame`

Comment: I've tried `switch_to.frame` as furas suggestion and it works! Thank you!